# How to group by a nested parameter

Tags: javascript, ruby, each, is-empty

How could I improve this code to doesn't use so many _.each and by doesn't always verifying the object emptyness of its properties

```
  _.each(initial_obj, function(value, key){
    _.each(value, function(value2, key2){
      _.each(value2, function(value3, key3){
        _.isEmpty(new_obj[key3]) && (new_obj[key3] = {});
        _.isEmpty(new_obj[key3][key]) && (new_obj[key3][key] = []);
        new_obj[key3][key][key2] = value3;
      })
    })
  })


old_obj: {'a': {'en', 'es', 'pt'}, 'b': {'en', 'es', 'pt'}, 'c': {'en', 'es', 'pt'}})

  new_obj: {'en': ['a': [], 'b': [], 'c': []},
                          'es': {'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': []},
                          'pt': {'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': []}
                          })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the keys of the object using [Object#keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a). Then iterate the inner array, with [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). For each string in the array, [assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) the `key` with an empty array:

```js
const obj = {'a': ['en', 'es', 'pt'], 'b': ['en', 'es', 'pt'], 'c': ['en', 'es', 'pt']};

const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((r, key) => {
  obj[key].forEach((str) => r[str] = Object.assign(r[str] || {}, { [key]: [] }));
  
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Open a new question, with the new valid data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46858413/how-to-group-by-a-mix-of-nested-parameter-objects-and-arrays ;]

Answer (score 0):

With Ruby:

```
h = { a: ['en', 'es', 'pt'], b: ['en', 'es', 'pt'], c: ['en', 'es', 'pt'] }

values = h.first.last
  #=> ["en", "es", "pt"]
h.keys.map { |k| [k, values.map  { |v| [v,[]] }.to_h] }.to_h
  #=> {:a=>{"en"=>[], "es"=>[], "pt"=>[]},
  #    :b=>{"en"=>[], "es"=>[], "pt"=>[]}, 
  #    :c=>{"en"=>[], "es"=>[], "pt"=>[]}}
```